# How to catch a 429 in Angular2?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

I'm trying to deal with a 429, but somehow I'm not able to catch it. Basically following the Angular example:

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                  .map(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError (error: Response | any) {
  // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
  let errMsg: string;
  if (error instanceof Response) {
    const body = error.json() || '';
    const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
    errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
  } else {
    errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
  }
  console.error(errMsg);
  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

I end up having a error status of 0:

```
Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers…}
```

What I want to achieve is basically is that I can catch it and retry it after some time. I came across the `retryWhen`, but I also have errors like 400 & 500 which I don't want to retry and just catch and report.